# Record syntax is illegal. Binary Tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

I defined the tree type with record syntax way.

```
data Tree a = Null | Node a {lTree:: Tree a, rTree :: Tree a}
```

However, when I load it, it shows an error:

```
• Record syntax is illegal here: {lTree :: Tree a, rTree :: Tree a}
    • In the type ‘{lTree :: Tree a, rTree :: Tree a}’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘Node’
      In the data declaration for ‘Tree’
  |
2 | data Tree a = Null | Node a {lTree:: Tree a, rTree :: Tree a}
  |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please make your post a bit more readable with formatting

Comment: By the way, it's inherently dangerous to use record syntax with multiple constructors. It makes the record accessors into partial functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `a` should also be part of the record syntax, for example:

```
data Tree a = Null | Node {valTree :: a, lTree:: Tree a, rTree :: Tree a}
```

You can not "mix" record syntax with positional syntax as is specified by the [Haskell grammar in the Haskell '98 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html):

> ```
> constr  -> con [!] atype1 ... [!] atypek  (arity con = k, k>=0)
>         |  (btype | ! atype) conop (btype | ! atype)  (infix conop)
>         |  con { fielddecl1 , ... , fielddecln }  (n>=0)
> ```